# Show Dialog box at center of its parent

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, positioning, center

It's been a mess to show a DialogBox at the center of its parent form. Here is a method to show a dialog.

I am positioning its parent to center but not able to center the DialogBox

```
private void OpenForm(Object point, Object height, Object width)
{
    FormLoading frm = new FormLoading();
    Point temp = (Point)point;
    Point location = new Point(temp.X + (int)((int)width) / 2, 
                               temp.Y + (int)((int)height) / 2);
    frm.Location = location;
    frm.ShowDialog();
}

private void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {                    
        ThreadStart starter= delegate { OpenForm(currentScreenLocation, 
                                                 this.Height, this.Width); };
        Thread t = new Thread(starter);
        t.Start();
        ////// Some functionality here...
        t.Abort();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also be careful with multithreading. Control's properties (at least those that deal with the User interface) can only be changed from the thread on which they are created. I don't see a bigger picture here so I don't know why you create each form in it's own thread, but keep that in mind.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You might want to check the `Form.StartPosition` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx

something along the lines of:

```
private void OpenForm(Form parent)
{
    FormLoading frm = new FormLoading();
    frm.Parent = parent;
    frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

This of course requires setting the form's parent.

Comment: frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            frm.Location = location;

I used it and worked for me :)

Comment: Setting it to FormStartPosition.CenterParent does the math for you. But I guess you would want to retain your code if you plan on doing anything more complex than centering. I'm glad you solved your problem.

Comment: FormStartPosition.CenterParent did not work for me. I just want to center it. But your provided link was a key for me. Thanks for that

Comment: `frm.Parent = parent;` doesn't work, but removing that line of code still works properly..  the parent thing gives a Top-Level error which couldn't be fixed. `Top-level control cannot be added to a control`

Comment: rather than `frm.Parent = parent`, I use `frm.Parent = this`

Comment: If you get the 'Top-Level control cannot be added...' exception try setting the Owner instead: `frm.Owner = parent;`

Comment: You can also pass the parent window to ShowDialog

Comment: @Nils +1 for `frm.Owner` as this works within the child form class.

Answer (score 14):

```
form1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7):

if you are making a custom MessageBox,you can simply put this:

```
CenterToParent();
```

in your custom MessageBox `formload()` method.

Answer (score 4):

In addition, if you want to set up arbitrary location you can use this

```
FormLoading frm = new FormLoading();
Point location = new Point(300, 400);
frm.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual;
frm.Location = location;
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NewForm.Show();

NewForm.Top = (this.Top + (this.Height / 2)) - NewForm.Height / 2;
NewForm.Left = (this.Left + (this.Width / 2)) - NewForm.Width / 2;
```